# What case and reason to use implication and conjunction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I must honestly to say that I cannot understand what and where, how to use the quantifier when its combined with logic connective, specifically implication and conjunction

In the someone's lecture, they have the problem:

"If a user is active, at least one network link will be available."

So let:

A(u) represent “User u is active.”

S(n, x) represent “Network link n is state x"

The result is: ∃u A(u) → ∃n S(n,available) , although I almost see ∃ is usually come with the "∧" conjunctions.So, I was think like Why can not it be:  ∃u A(u) ∧ ∃n S(n,available)

In short, is that "the quantifier" is not mostly decided "What the logic connective" can be? and We have to based on the context to decide the logic connective too ?Thanks all

Comment: In this case, because the "implication" is outer wrt the quantifierss... Compare with "There is a Human that is a Male" that is $\exists x (M(x) \land H(x))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The result is: ∃u A(u) → ∃n S(n, available) , although I almost see ∃
> is usually come with the "∧" conjunctions.

True, but in this case, the '→' is outside of the scope of the first '∃'. Shown with implicit bracketing:

∃u **[** A(u) **]** → ∃n **[** S(n, available) **]**

> So, I was think like Why can not it be:  ∃u A(u) ∧ ∃n S(n, available)

That is not a conditional statement. It states, in effect, that user *u* is active **and** that at least one link is active.

Comment: Oh, again Thanks u for that explatation!So that If I placed the ∃u after the → then the statement will be wrong, right?

Comment: Yes. Your original solution was correct. The [ ]'s I inserted are optional because there is only a single term within the scope of both ∃. They are implied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that too